# use xslt to change XML array type

Tags: xslt

I have source XML like this

```
<person>
    <name>Alex</name>
    <name>David</name>
    <name>Ray</name>
    <height>170</height>
    <height>160</height>
    <height>172</height>
    <weight>80</weight>
    <weight>70</weight>
    <weight>64</weight>
</person>
```

but need to mapping like this

```
<person>
    <name>Alex</name>
    <height>170</height>
    <weight>80</weight>
</person>
<person>
    <name>David</name>
    <height>160</height>
    <weight>70</weight>
</person>
<person>
    <name>Ray</name>
    <height>172</height>
    <weight>64</weight>
</person>
```

and I don't know total person count, how to use xslt do it?

Comment: Please state which version of XSLT you use. Also, are those child element names like `name`, `height` and `weight` known when writing the XSLT?

Comment: version="1.0", thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the attributes of a person are linked by their position, you can do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/person">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="name">
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
            <person>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../height[$i]"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../weight[$i]"/>
            </person>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note the added `root` element in the output; without it, the result will be a result tree fragment, not a well-formed XML document.